# useState not re-rendering component if it is called inside callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a component to upload a video and I am trying to show the progress bar.
Here is my core code.

```
const Upload = () => {
  const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0);
  console.log(percent); // This logs uploaded percentage every time progListener callback is called. From 0 to 100.
  const dropAccepted = async () => {
    const params = {...} // parameters to upload video like filename, file
    await APIs.uploadVideo(params, progListener);
  }
  const progListener = (event) => {
    var p = Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total)
    // console.log(p) logs uploaded percentage from 0 to 100
    setPercent(p);
  }

  return (
    <h6>{percent}</h6>  
    <Dropzone onDropAccepted={dropAccepted}/>
  )
}
```

On progListener callback, I have updated the percent with **setPercent** function so I think **h6** should print uploaded percentage. But it always 0.
What's wrong on my code? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Use useRef instead of useState

Comment: can you try: setPercent(() => Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total));

Comment: @Syder, I tried your solution but no luck.

Comment: @ThanveerShah, can you plz give me an sample how can I use useRef instead useState?

Comment: Could we see `console.log(p)` and `console.log(percent)` logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update it with useRef,

The reason why useState doesnt show the latest value is because useState is asynchronous. So in your case useState is being updated without giving it a chance to re-render. In these cases useRef plays a better role.

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";

const Upload = () => {
  const percent = useRef(0);

  const progListener = (event) => {
      percent.current = Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total)
  }

  return (
    <h6>{percent.current}</h6>  
    <Dropzone onDropAccepted={dropAccepted}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Thanveer. This works like a charm. Btw, can you plz explain me what's wrong on my code? Why my code not working?

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please accept the answer and give an upvote. this will show others that is a working solution . :)

Comment: Yes. I will accept your answer. Btw, in my understanding, after **setPercent** is called, it re-render the component. And actually, after **setPercent** is called, **console.log(percent);** is called and logged the updated percent. It doesn't mean component is re-rendered?